# \pgfmathprintnumber label of bar values exceeding axis values

Tags: pgfplots, labels, bar-chart, pgfmath

I'm trying to only have the y-value exceeding the axis to be labelled and not the rest (as shown in the picture below). Is there any suggestion how this can be made?[image]

my MWE (thanks to [@Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88892/pgfplots-bar-plot-spacing-inbetween-bars/88896#88896)):

```
    \documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}


\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 0.9*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=4pt,
        ymin=0,
        axis on top,
        ymax=12,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        xtick = data,
        xlabel = {Environmental indicators},
        symbolic x coords={GWP, ODP, POCP, AP, EP(T), EP(FW), EP(M), ADP, CED},
        restrict y to domain*=0:14, % Cut values off at 14
    visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
    after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
     \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=1pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1.05) -- (rel axis cs:1,1.05);
        },
    nodes near coords={%
     \pgfmathprintnumber{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
        },
    axis lines*=left,
    clip=false
    ]
\addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none}]
            coordinates {   (GWP, 1.0) 
                            (ODP,1.0)
                            (POCP,1.0)
                            (AP,1.0)
                            (EP(T),1.0)
                            (EP(FW),1.0)
                            (EP(M),1.0)
                            (ADP,1.0)
                            (CED,1.0)};
        \addplot[style={rred,fill=rred,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(GWP,0.11) 
                            (ODP,4.28) 
                            (POCP,0.28 )
                            (AP,0.67)
                            (EP(T),0.38)
                            (EP(FW),1.0)
                            (EP(M),0.55)
                            (ADP,4.20)
                            (CED,1.0)};
        \addplot[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(GWP,1.42)
                            (ODP,1.37) 
                            (POCP,1.26)
                            (AP,6.50)
                            (EP(T),6.65)
                            (EP(FW),48.56)
                            (EP(M),2.97)
                            (ADP,2.25)
                            (CED,1.0)};
\addplot[style={ppurple,fill=ppurple,mark=none}]
             coordinates {  (GWP,0.74) 
                            (ODP,2.07) 
                            (POCP,2.69)
                            (AP,7.10)
                            (EP(T),3.03)
                            (EP(FW),6.88)
                            (EP(M),3.04)
                            (ADP,2.53)
                            (CED,1.0)};
\legend{Singapore,France,Germany,Spain}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Comparison of electricity profiles per 1 kWh of electricity}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Are you searching for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365826/95441?

Comment: @StefanPinnow thanks for your reply, unfortunately not quite what i wanted. I still want the bar protruding out the axis and also the white line acting as a "break".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps to get this.  The first is that you need to remove `nodes near coords` and its value from the `\begin[axis]` parameter list.  (This removes *all* labels).  Next, you need to add `nodes near coords` into the individual `\addplot` with the green bars.  Doing this, you are stuck with all the green bars having a title, which is obviously not exactly what you need.

However, there is a trick to only added `nodes near coords` value on the particular coordinate that you want.  (You count coordinates starting from an index of 0).  So, in this case, `(EP(FW),48.56)` is the sixth item but index 5.  Take the value `{\pgfmathprintnumber{\rawy}}` from above and wrap it with `\ifnum...\fi` as this example shows:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}


\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 0.9*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=4pt,
        ymin=0,
        axis on top,
        ymax=12,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        xtick = data,
        xlabel = {Environmental indicators},
        symbolic x coords={GWP, ODP, POCP, AP, EP(T), EP(FW), EP(M), ADP, CED},
        restrict y to domain*=0:14, % Cut values off at 14
    visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
    after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
     \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=1pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1.05) -- (rel axis cs:1,1.05);
        },
    %nodes near coords={%
     %\pgfmathprintnumber{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
     %},%REMOVED THIS PART
    axis lines*=left,
    clip=false
    ]
\addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none}]
            coordinates {(GWP, 1.0) 
                            (ODP,1.0)
                            (POCP,1.0)
                            (AP,1.0)
                            (EP(T),1.0)
                            (EP(FW),1.0)
                            (EP(M),1.0)
                            (ADP,1.0)
                            (CED,1.0)};
        \addplot[style={rred,fill=rred,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(GWP,0.11) 
                            (ODP,4.28) 
                            (POCP,0.28 )
                            (AP,0.67)
                            (EP(T),0.38)
                            (EP(FW),1.0)
                            (EP(M),0.55)
                            (ADP,4.20)
                            (CED,1.0)};
        \addplot[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none},nodes near coords={\ifnum\coordindex=5{\pgfmathprintnumber{\rawy}}\else\fi}]%UPDATED THIS WITH A CONDITIONAL
             coordinates {(GWP,1.42)
                            (ODP,1.37) 
                            (POCP,1.26)
                            (AP,6.50)
                            (EP(T),6.65)
                            (EP(FW),48.56)
                            (EP(M),2.97)
                            (ADP,2.25)
                            (CED,1.0)};
        \addplot[style={ppurple,fill=ppurple,mark=none}]
             coordinates {  (GWP,0.74) 
                            (ODP,2.07) 
                            (POCP,2.69)
                            (AP,7.10)
                            (EP(T),3.03)
                            (EP(FW),6.88)
                            (EP(M),3.04)
                            (ADP,2.53)
                            (CED,1.0)};
\legend{Singapore,France,Germany,Spain}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Comparison of electricity profiles per 1 kWh of electricity}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with only one bar having a label]

EDIT:

In case you are interested, I was able to adapt this from [a somewhat similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281044/78866).